# What's the research criteria for PhD graduation?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, thesis, united-states

I'm studying CS in USA. I'm wondering how many papers do PhDs need to graduate? Why isn't there a specific well-defined rule (i.e. you must have 4 papers in a high ranked conference, etc.)?

Ive heard that it's mainly your adviser's decision to let you graduate or not. So is it possible to find a super lax adviser that will let you graduate very early? Why don't professors let students graduate faster, so the professor can have more graduated PhD students which would make them look good on paper?

Comment: Specific “rules” get gamed. Leading to more ineffective rules. Real life has no specific rules.

Comment: Your dissertation is approved by a committee; usually the other professors on the committee will go along with what your advisors say, but they won't if the standards are unreasonably lax (and there are other solutions if they are unreasonably strong).  Also, having more students doesn't make you look better on paper; rather, it's having more successful after the PhD students that makes you look better.

Comment: Why do you want to graduate quickly? Isn't it better to pace yourself, gain a thorough understanding of your research topic and write a really good thesis?

Comment: Absolutely right @JonCuster People always find ways to satisfy the conditions to graduate early, with little knowledge in real-life.

Answer (score 4):

A PhD is supposed to indicate that you are qualified to do independent and worthy research. This is not the same as publishing X papers in journals of quality Y: In some disciplines writing a thesis demonstrates this, in others one does so by publishing papers. But it is clear that even in the latter kind of discipline, if you were to write a spectacular paper that illustrates a great idea and sustained follow-up in terms of broad evaluation of how that idea works in practice, you will have demonstrated that you deserve a PhD. On the other hand, being fourth author on 7 papers where all you've done is tally up the numbers, it's equally clear that you have not demonstrated what is required to obtain a PhD.

In other words, the source of confusion in your question is that what you are asked to demonstrate for a PhD may be *related*, but is not *equal* to any specific publication requirement.

This also gets to your second question: Why don't (most) professors graduate students quickly? It's because professors' professional duty is to enforce the standards of their profession. They would be acting unprofessionally if they graduated students without the students satisfying the expectations of a PhD.

Comment: so when looking for an adviser, is it possible for me to to find one that will let me graduate faster?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. It is certainly possible to find an adviser who is willing to let you graduate *when you have demonstrated that you are worthy of holding a PhD*, regardless of whether you have published 2, 4, or 8 papers. You should expect that no honorable adviser will let you graduate if you have not demonstrated that you are worthy of a PhD, even if you have published 8 papers.

Comment: What exactly is this worthiness? seems like some subjective criteria ready to be abused

Comment: @JobHunter69 Welcome to the real world. Nobody ever said that "critical thinking" and "independence" are easy to measure, yet that's what your future employers want you to have.

Comment: I'm already employed now. The hiring here is way more objective. In fact, more objective than university exams.

Comment: Sounds like you're in the right place already then.